# Where are the compiled typescript js files for my react-native expo application?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I just created one of the default typescript expo projects with `expo init`, and it has a simple `App.tsx` file in the main directory. I'm able to make changes to the file and have those changes reflected in my app, but I can't seem to find the corresponding output file:`App.js` file anywhere, which I find very confusing.

After digging in the provided `tsconfig.json`, it has an option clearly labeled `"noEmit": true,` which turns off any output files during the compilation, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

**Where are the typescript output files being saved / watched?**

Answer (score 3):

React Native use [Metro](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/concepts) to bundle javascript/typescript files. The file generated are cached, and stored in some kind of hashed directory structure which can't be read directly.

You can add those options into `metro.config.js` to redirect the cache folder

```
const path = require('path');
const { FileStore } = require('metro-cache');

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  cacheStores: [
    new FileStore({
      root: path.join(__dirname, 'metro-cache')
    })
  ]
};
```