# How is TypeScript giving me feedback without running tsc?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am following the steps to add typescript to an existing react native project [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#adding-typescript-to-an-existing-project). The last step says:

`Run yarn tsc to type-check your new TypeScript files.`

But when I look at VSCode, I already see feedback from typescript. Is it really necessary to use `tsc` with react native? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359292/where-are-the-compiled-typescript-js-files-for-my-react-native-expo-application#:%7E:text=React%20Native%20use%20Metro%20to%20bundle%20javascript/typescript%20files.%20The%20file%20generated%20are%20cached%2C%20and%20stored%20in%20some%20kind%20of%20hashed%20directory%20structure%20which%20can%27t%20be%20read%20directly.) says you don't even need an `outDir` and the [RN documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#where-to-find-useful-advice:%7E:text=%22node%22%2C-,%22noEmit%22%3A%20true%2C,-%22strict%22%3A) indeed says to set `noEmit` to `true`. Thank you!

Comment: vscode includes typescript out of the box

Comment: It's necessary for *somebody* to run `tsc` in order to get typechecking information from Typescript. Whether that somebody is you or an IDE is irrelevant.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code includes the TS language server out of the box which is why you were getting first-class TS support without manually configuring anything. However, in order to build/run your application, you will have to set up some sort of build tool that will call `tsc` under the hood.